# Check if the user has flagged content with any flag

Tags: 7, theming

It is possible with the following code to check if a content has been flagged by the current user with a certain flag:

```
$flag = flag_get_flag('flag_name');
if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($node->nid, $GLOBALS['user']->uid)) {
  print "This node is flagged";
}
```

But, how to check if the user has flagged content with any flag ?

Answer (score 0):

The flag module has a utility function [`flag_get_flags()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/flag/-/blob/673142d9a3548e696d8176070b771824de56b41e/flag.module#L1925) that retrieves multiple flags, with an option to filter on the entity type of the flag:

```
// Same logic, looped over multiple node flags:
$flags = flag_get_flags('node')
foreach ($flags as $flag_name => $flag) {
  if ($flag && $flag->is_flagged($node->nid, $GLOBALS['user']->uid)) {
    print "This node is flagged";
  }
}
```